# Convert pdb to exe file?

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have developed windows phone apps in visual studio 2013 using windows phone 8 SDK. This is my project and I don't know how to execute exe file, In my bin folder its will be .pdb file so how to change these into .exe file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Phone, there are nothing called execute .exe file. Instead, WP users install an app using app package: a .xap file.

When you build your project, if success, VS create a .xap file in your project debug folder or release folder. Go to your project and search for ".xap" file. If you submit your app to the Store, you need to upload this ".xap" file.

Comment: OK ,Can you tell the procedure for submit into Store?

Comment: First, your build .xap file for ARM architecture. Then prepare some screenshots , icon, think about app name, keywords.
Create your Dev Account, and submit your app. The submission process is easy to follow, it's step by step.

Comment: Thanks for your reply